# Why can't curly braces be used as a delimiter for \verb? i.e. \verb{foo}

Tags: verbatim

When I try to do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 Hello \verb{foo}.                                                                                                     
\end{document}
```

i.e. use braces as a delimiter for `\verb` I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \verb ended by end of line.
```

Is there a reason why you have to use `|` or `+` or some other delimiter? The documentation I found online suggests any delimiter (other than `*`) should work. But curly braces don't seem to work.

Comment: TeXnically speaking, `{` and `}` are not delimiters. They have a different catcode. If they are converted to active chars then things are bound to break.

Comment: @percusse: You don't need to define `{` and `}` to be active to use them as delimiters. For example, in ConTeXt, you may use `\type{...}` for verbatim text. Of course, LaTeX like `\type|..|` or `\type+...+` also works. Ditto for ConTeXt packages like `filter` and `vim` module that work with verbatim text.

Comment: @Aditya I might be wrong but I think verb defines the next char to be active to collect the content in between. Baaah I meant the `\dospecials`

Comment: @percusse: I haven't looked to LaTeX's definition, but ConTeXt does not make a character active. Basically, it grabs the next char, checks if it is `\bgroup`; if so uses one definition, else uses 2nd definition. See, for example, [this implementation](https://github.com/adityam/filter/blob/master/t-filter.mkiv#L253) in `t-filter`.

Comment: As @Aditya says, you can set up to grab verbatim material in braces: `xparse` does this as the `v`-type argument.

Comment: @JosephWright thanks for the pointer to `xparse` and the `v` argument. Ultimately, I'd like to define my own command that can grab verbatim text between braces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the relevant code from `latex.ltx`

```
\def\verb{\relax\ifmmode\hbox\else\leavevmode\null\fi
  \bgroup
    \verb@eol@error \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
    \verbatim@font\@noligs
    \@ifstar\@sverb\@verb}
```

The `\verb` command doesn't have any argument; it does some preliminary work and then hands control to `\@verb` or `\@sverb` (the latter if it was called as `\verb*`.

```
\def\@verb{\@vobeyspaces \frenchspacing \@sverb}
```

Here we see that `\@verb` simply makes the space active (already defined to expand to `\space`) and sets `\frenchspacing` for keeping all spaces equal; then it calls `\@sverb`

```
\def\@sverb#1{%
  \catcode`#1\active
  \lccode`\~`#1%
  \gdef\verb@balance@group{\verb@egroup
     \@latex@error{\noexpand\verb illegal in command argument}\@ehc}%
  \aftergroup\verb@balance@group
  \lowercase{\let~\verb@egroup}}
```

Now `\@sverb` reads the first token (the delimiter) and makes it active. Then it defines a check macro for getting out of troubles in case `\verb` is called as the argument to a command.

Finally it defines the active delimiter to be `\verb@egroup`; upon finding and expanding it, all the special settings for verbatim mode will be undone.

Thus `\verb{xyz{` is legal (try it) but `\verb{xyz}` isn't. The code *might* be changed to take care of `\verb{xyz}`; however, one of the main points of `\verb` is allowing unbalanced braces in the verbatim text, so there's not so much to gain with that.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I wanted `\verb` to behave like a standard latex command. Obviously `{` and `}` are different characters. I never thought that you might want to have unbalanced braces.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use *matching* "delimiters". And, in this instance, `{` does not *match* `}`. `\verb` grabs the first (non-`*` character) and makes it active, in order to match it with the same character at the of the verbatim content, thereby defining a scope over which the verbatim protocol acts.

The choice between using `*` or not is based on the fact that LaTeX sometimes provides a starred variant of a command. In terms of `\verb`, this is also the case as it executes `\@ifstar` (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\verb{\relax\ifmmode\hbox\else\leavevmode\null\fi
  \bgroup
    \verb@eol@error \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
    \verbatim@font\@noligs
    \@ifstar\@sverb\@verb}
```

The [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides a similar `verbatim`-style macro using `lstlistings` (for the environment) and `\lstinline` (for the in-line usage). From the [`listings` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (section **4.2 Typesetting listings**, p 25) it notes that you have to provide the `<character>`...`<same character>` pattern:

```
\lstinline[<key=value list>]<character><source code><same character>
```

Only recently has an "experimental" `\lstinline[..]{...}` been provided. However, for similar reasons and making the coding behind it more complicated, using it in the traditional sense should be adequate.