# Use of " in verbatim mode

Tags: verbatim

I would like to use the symbol `"` inside `\verb`. Is that possible? For example, in

```
\verb"abc"defg"
```

the second `"` will be interpreted as the end of the verbatim environment though my intention is that the whole string `abc"defg` is in verbatim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use different delimiters for the `verb` command, such as `!`

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\verb!abc"defg!
\end{document}
```

As detailed in [Why can't curly braces be used as a delimiter for \verb? i.e. \verb{foo}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106394/why-cant-curly-braces-be-used-as-a-delimiter-for-verb-i-e-verbfoo) you can use any character you like for the delimiter, provided that it isn't `*`. So, for example, any of the following will work

- `\verb&abc"defg&`
- `\verb3abc"defg3`
- `\verb^abc"defg^`

Of course, the sense in using such delimiters may be questionable.